# How to get a field and a field into of array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this json in MongoDB:

```js
{

    _id: ObjectId("630fbb09cc9deb16a33fbcde"),
    firmness: {
      name: 'hard',
      url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry-firmness/3/'
    },
    flavors: [
      {
        flavor: {
          name: 'spicy',
          url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry-flavor/1/'
        },
        potency: 10
      },
      {
        flavor: {
          name: 'dry',
          url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry-flavor/2/'
        },
        potency: 0
      },
      {
        flavor: {
          name: 'sweet',
          url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry-flavor/3/'
        },
        potency: 0
      },
      {
        flavor: {
          name: 'bitter',
          url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry-flavor/4/'
        },
        potency: 0
      },
      {
        flavor: {
          name: 'sour',
          url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/berry-flavor/5/'
        },
        potency: 10
      }
    ],
    growth_time: 2,
    id: 20,
    item: { name: 'pinap-berry', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/item/145/' },
    max_harvest: 10,
    name: 'pinap',
    natural_gift_power: 70,
    natural_gift_type: { name: 'grass', url: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/12/' },
    size: 80,
    smoothness: 20,
    soil_dryness: 35
  }
```

And I want to get the `soil_dryness` field and the field called `"name"` into flavor list from `'flavors'` array.

How can I do that?

I tried with:

```js
db.Berries.find({},{soil_dryness:1},{"flavors.$":1}).pretty().limit(20)
```

But unfortunately doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Query

- project, the `soil_dryness` and the names, path in arrays = array with the values, here the names

*not sure if this the output you need, if its not if you can add the expected ouput you need

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6310ff9978a49d8782851495)

```js
db.Berries.aggregate(
[{"$project": {"soil_dryness": 1, "names": "$flavors.flavor.name"}},
 {"$limit": 20}])
```